# Having trouble about 6 errors in my array code

Tags: c++, arrays

I can't seem to correctly run the code. Would be of a great help in finding the 6 errors. I am stuck and somehow no idea where to find the error for my simple array code.

Here are the errors I get.

[image]

```
// This program uses two arrays to record the names of 6 types of pizza
// and the sales numbers for each of these types
// The program then finds the best and the worst selling pizzas

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    constint ARR_SIZE = 6; // Declare the array size and set it to 6
    // Declare the array of pizza names and record values in it
    int name[ARR_SIZE] = [ "Pepperoni", "Prosciutto", "Vegetarian",
        "Sausage",
        "Supreme",
        "Mozzarella" ];
    int sales[ARR_SIZE]; // Declare the sales array
    int worstseller_number, bestseller_number; // The subscripts of the best- and worstseller
    string worstseller_name, bestseller_name; // The sale numbers of the best- and worstseller

    for (int i = 1; i < ARR_SIZE; i++) // A loop to enter all sales numbers

    {
        cout << "Enter sales for " << name[i] << ": ";
        cin >> sales[i];
    }

    // Make the first element in name[] the bestseller and the worstseller name
    worstseller_name = bestseller_name = name[0];

    // Make the first element in sales[] the bestseller and the worstseller sales amount
    worstseller_number = bestseller_number = sales[0];

    for (int i = 0; i <= ARR_SIZE; i++) // Loop through all elements in sales[]
    {
        if (sales[i] < worstseller_number) // If an element is less than the lowest...
        {
            worstseller_number = i; // make the lowest sales equal to its sales
            worstseller_name = name[i]; // make the worstseller name equal to its name
        }

        if (sales[i] < bestseller_number) // If an element is higher than the highest...
        {
            bestseller_number = sales[i]; // make the highest sales equal to its sales
            bestseller_name = name[i]; // make the bestseller name equal to its name
        }
    }

    cout << "The bestselling pizza is " << bestseller_name << " with the sales of "
         << bestseller_number << endl; // Display the best selling pizza
    cout << "The worst selling pizza is " << worstseller_name << " with the sales of "
         << worstseller_number << endl;
} // display the worst selling pizza
```

Comment: What kind of errors do you get? Compiler errors? Please copy and paste them into the question. Incorrect output? Please provide inputs, output and expected output.

Comment: "_I can't seem to correctly run the code. Would be of a great help in finding the 6 errors._" What errors, do you get, when trying to compile this code?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I have included a link to the image of the errors

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I added a link for the errors

Comment: For future questions, please copy and paste errors into the question as text, not as image. Have you tried to solve the errors from the top? First error tells you that compiler doesn't know what `constint` is supposed to mean. How can you fix it?

Comment: You need to get yourself a good introductory book to the C++ programming language, start reading it and work through the exercises.  These mistakes you are making are bizarre, as the syntax is not C++ at all.

Comment: It seems like you could just use `std::minmax()` and be done with it.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen constant isnt it? man typo sorry.

Comment: @Potatou_ "_I added a link for the errors_" Errors need to be copied into the question, as text, not hidden behind 3rd party links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all it should be `const int ARR_SIZE = 6;` Next, your array elements are strings but you are defining the array as int. Another error is that when you declare an array, it should be enclosed within curly brackets instead of square brackets. There was a mistake in the logic when you were trying to accept the sales and calculate the min and max which I have fixed. The first for loop should start from i=0 and the second for loop should go till `i<ARR_SIZE`

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int ARR_SIZE = 6; // Declare the array size and set it to 6
    // Declare the array of pizza names and record values in it
    string name[ARR_SIZE] = {"Pepperoni", "Prosciutto", "Vegetarian",
        "Sausage",
        "Supreme",
        "Mozzarella"};
    int sales[ARR_SIZE]; // Declare the sales array
    int worstseller_number, bestseller_number; // The subscripts of the best- and worstseller
    string worstseller_name, bestseller_name; // The sale numbers of the best- and worstseller

    for (int i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++) // A loop to enter all sales numbers

    {
        cout << "Enter sales for " << name[i] << ": ";
        cin >> sales[i];
    }

    // Make the first element in name[] the bestseller and the worstseller name
    worstseller_name = bestseller_name = name[0];
    // Make the first element in sales[] the bestseller and the worstseller sales amount
    worstseller_number = bestseller_number = sales[0];

    for (int i = 0; i <ARR_SIZE; i++) // Loop through all elements in sales[]
    {
        if (sales[i] < worstseller_number) // If an element is less than the lowest...
        {
            worstseller_number = sales[i]; // make the lowest sales equal to its sales
            worstseller_name = name[i]; // make the worstseller name equal to its name
        }

        if (sales[i] > bestseller_number) // If an element is higher than the highest...
        {
            bestseller_number = sales[i]; // make the highest sales equal to its sales
            bestseller_name = name[i]; // make the bestseller name equal to its name
        }
    }

    cout << "The bestselling pizza is " << bestseller_name << " with the sales of "
         << bestseller_number << endl; // Display the best selling pizza
    cout << "The worst selling pizza is " << worstseller_name << " with the sales of "
         << worstseller_number << endl;
} // display the worst selling pizza
```

Comment: You should at least attempt to fix ALL the issues with the code if you are going to post a modified version of it as an answer.  By that I mean not only the syntax errors but also the logical errors and undefined behavior.

Comment: Thanks man it finally works. however, the bestseller and worst seller are the same. The bestsellers grabs the value and name of the worstseller as well.

Comment: @Potatou_ Fixed the logic in the recent edited code. Please check it whether it works.

Comment: @paddy I have done the same in the recent edit

Comment: Yes, it looks better.  But YOU should ensure it works, not them.  They are clearly a beginner, here seeking advice.  Identify everything they got wrong, and explain why it's wrong.  Points for style would be to remove the absurd amount of pointless comments that make this code unreadable.  Extra points for style would be to remove `using namespace std;`.  Further points for not copying strings every time you update the min or max.  Arguable points for not using `std::endl`.  And final style points for recommending standard library functions that can do this stuff.